# Cardinality of quasiaffine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

The excercise 1.4.8(a) of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry says

> Show that any variety of positive dimension over $k$ has the same cardinality as $k$.

Using Hartshorne's notation, we define a quasi-affine variety as an open subset of an affine variety. I was able to prove the hint given in the excercise based on this claim

> **Claim.** Let $X$ be an affine variety and $W\subset X$ a quasi-affine variety, then $|X| = |W|$

Over $\mathbb A^1$ its obvious, but I can't prove the general case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since a positive-dimensional variety $X$ is contained in a projective space, and it is easy to see that the latter have the cardinality of the field, it is enough to show that $X$ has a least the cardinality of the field. If you show that there is a an open set $U\subseteq X$ and a surjective regular function $f:U\to k$, then you are done.