# On cardinality of varieties (Hartshorne I.4.8, following Hartshorne's hint)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, cardinals

In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry Exercise I.4.8,

> **Exercise**: Show that any variety of positive dimension over $k $ has the same cardinality as $ k $.

> **Hints**: Do $\mathbb{A}^{n} $ and $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ first. Then for any $ X $, use induction on the dimension $ n $. Use (4.9) to make $ X $ birational to a hypersurface $ H \subset\mathbb{P}^{n+1 }$. Use (Ex. 3.7) to show that the projection of $  H$ to $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ from a point not on $ H$ is finite-to-one and surjective.

Although this has been asked in many posts in MSE, namely:[Cardinality of variety](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869125/cardinality-of-variety) and [Cardinality of quasiaffine variety](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447819/cardinality-of-quasiaffine-variety) . My question is different. In these posts, it seems that the proof provided (although they are indeed wonderful and helpful) did not follow the hints by Hartshorne. I tried to follow the hints, but didn't get the promising results.

So my **question** is: How to finish this exercise using the methods provided in the **HINTS**?

**My attempts**:

(1) I had made some attempts and found that using Noether normalisation theorem, we may direct prove the desired result. Maybe I will post an answer using this in the posts mentioned above. Yet I still hope to know how to follow the hint.

(2) I have managed to prove that the cardinality of $\mathbb{A}^{n} $ and $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ are the same as the cardinality of the ground algebraically closed field $k$. Yet what's next?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_theorem_about_choice

Comment: It's rare for perfect texts to be published, and Hartshorne's no exception - there are occasional (or more than occasional, depending on who you ask) lemons and hints that aren't quite as useful as they could be. Following the hint you'd make $X\sim H$, then project $H$ to $\Bbb P^n$, and show the image of the open isomorphic to an open in $X$ contains a nontrivial open subset of $\Bbb P^n$, and then if you can show that a nontrivial open subset of $\Bbb P^n$ has cardinality $|k|$, you're done. But there's no need to prove that last bit by induction - and many solutions don't.

Comment: All this is to say that I sympathize with your plight of not understanding what Hartshorne's going for in the hint, and that's the best I could think of under the circumstances. Perhaps someone else will have a better idea what Hartshorne's intent was.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you for your comments! Yet could you explain more on the line "......and show the image of the open isomorphic to an open in $X$ contains a nontrivial open subset of $\mathbb{P}^n$". I don't know how to understand this sentence. (So sorry since English is a foreign language for me.)

Comment: $X$ birational to $H$ means that there's open subsets $U\subset X$ and $W\subset H$ so that $U\cong W$ - in particular, this is a bijection. Next, letting $\pi: H\to \Bbb P^n$ be the projection, we want to show that $\pi(W)$ contains a nonempty open set in $\Bbb P^n$.

Comment: @KReiser Thank you so much for your comments!

Comment: @KentaS Sorry but I viewed the wikipedia page, do you mean that we can use the following **Tarski's theorem about choice**: For every infinite set $A$, there is a bijective map between the sets $A$ and $A \times A$. And "Trichotomy: If two sets are given, then either they have the same cardinality, or one has a smaller cardinality than the other. Given two non-empty sets, one has a surjection to the other." But I cannot see the relation of this theorem to my question. Could you clarify it? Thank you :)